# How load a specific sheet from a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet that contains a lot of sheets, and I need to load one of these sheets, how can I do that?

Here is a photo of the sheets in my Spreadsheet
[image: sheets]

Here is my idea how to do it:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(index).getSheetByName('Geração de Demanda');
```

Should that be working?

Comment: thanks for accepting. I assumed you wanted the UI to reflect your selection. If you don't need that and only want to read a value on this particular sheet then your suggestion is sufficient : `var xxx=SpreadsheetApp.openById(index).getSheetByName('Geração de Demanda').getRange(1,1).getValue()` will indeed give value of A1 in this sheet.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're almost there... what you want is to make that sheet 'active' so try this :

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Geração de Demanda'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope all is well at your end,

You can also create a drop down list with all sheets names and run below script to automatically go to designated sheet.

```
function goto () {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var nameRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2);//the drop down is in B2 cell
var nameValue = nameRange.getValue();

ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(nameValue));

}
```

Hope that will help too

Have a good one

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But still...
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

I guess this is the most convenient way, as you dont have to deal with name, just indicate sheet number... [1] indicates second sheet... As you may guess numbering starts from 0 and on...

Comment: How do you know which sheet is which without referring to a unique name?  How does the follow on programmer on this job know which tabbed sheet is which, which one came first?  This method can add confusion.